# flatten object to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I want to transform an object like this:

```
[
  { name: 'john', surname: 'doe' },
  { name: 'jane', surname: 'dee' },
]
```

Into an array, like this. By choosing an arbitrary key (e.g: 'name')

```
[ 'john', 'jane' ]
```

What is the fastest way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the slowest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function like this

```
[
    { name: 'john', surname: 'doe' },
    { name: 'jane', surname: 'dee' },
].map(function(a){return a.name;})
```

Comment: Note that `Array#map` is an ES5 thing, but that's fine, this is NodeJS. (In client-side stuff, older browsers would need a shim.)

Comment: @Peter: No worries. :-) We should clean up these comments. I've done mine. This comment will auto-destruct in 10...9...8...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need retro compatibility (and I think you're not going to need it, since you're on NodeJS), you can simply use:

```
var obj = [
    { name: 'john', surname: 'doe' },
    { name: 'jane', surname: 'dee' },
],
    names = obj.map(function(item) {return item.name;});
```

Or, the "slowest" way:

```
var names = []; //obj defined before
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) 
    names.push(obj[i].name);
```

Comment: Ironically, it turns out `Array.prototype.map` is generally slower than a simple `for` loop. The native `map` function just *does more* error checking internally and has the overhead of an additional function invocation for every iteration: http://jsperf.com/array-map-test

Comment: @Peter, I know, in fact I put the quotes because it's not slowest at any point, it's just "slower" to write :P

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/), you can simply write:

```
names = _.pluck(obj, 'name');
```